# Trying to display multiple characters, Error: cannot convert void to System.Threading.ThreadStart

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm a newbie, trying to create multiple threads to display arrays of characters on console.

```
public static void Display(char[] array)
{
    // display flowing characters of an array at random WindowWidth point
}

public static char[] GenerateArray(int length)
{
    ....// generating array
    return array;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random randLen = new Random();
    int length;

    while (true)
    {
        length = randLen.Next(3, 10);
        Thread thread = new Thread(Display(GenerateArray(length)));
        thread.Start();
    }
 }
```

line:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(Display(GenerateArray(length)));
```

leads to an error: "Argument1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

As I understand, I can't assign a void value to the thread. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a new method (that does not take any arguments) to handle the random number generation, and displaying of generated arrays, then execute it using `new ThreadStart(void() )` method.

Your code should look something like this ...

```
public static void Display(char[] array)
    {
        // display flowing characters of an array at random WindowWidth point
    }

    public static char[] GenerateArray(int length)
    {
        // generating array
        //return array;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(displayRandomArray));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void displayRandomArray()
    {
        Random randLen = new Random();
        int length;
        length = randLen.Next(3, 10);
        Display(GenerateArray(length));
    }
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of parameter to object:

```
public static void Display(Object array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Lambda Expression

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()=>Display(x));
```